# How to deploy SpringBoot application (.war) on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have made sample Springboot application having below code in `application.propertied`

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/SpringSecurity.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=SpringSecurity
```

Also below two methods are in main class of SpringBoot

```
      @Bean
      public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat =
            new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
              @Override
              protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
              }
            };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
      }

      private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8082);
        return connector;
      }
```

If I run this application in tomcat like https://localhost:8082/hello , it works as it is self signed. If I hit http://localhost:8082/hello, tomcat shows bad request as expected. In fact, it also redirect from 8080 to 8082 too.

Now I export it as `.war` file.

Now I create a application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk by uploading above war file.

if I run the generated url : `http://SpringSecurity-env.eba-wwpkejwp.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/hello`, it works which I am not expecting as it is http.

I need to work on https. Can someone suggest me what should I configure/add/remove on AWS/war file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your application work through HTTPs, the easiest way involves:

- using **load balanced EB environment** with Application Load Balancer,
- registering your **own domain**, e.g. in Route53. Your domain is required as you can only register valid public SSL certificates (not self-signed) for a domain which you control.
- once you have domain, you can **request free SSL** certificate for it in ACM.
- then you deploy the SSL certificate on the ALB using **HTTPS listener**.

Related **AWS docs**:

- [Creating an Amazon Route 53 record that routes traffic to your Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-resource-record-set)
- [How can I configure HTTPS for my Elastic Beanstalk environment?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/)
- [Configuring HTTPS for your Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html)